# Written test case with pytest for data validation, The nature of the test case changes with group execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am using pytest to write unit test case for data validation,Each test case is written inside method. when i run each test cases individually it gives the correct result, but when i try to run all test cases together it makes pass the failed test cases. I would have used pytest ordering, but i have 400 test cases. can anyone suggest me a solution?

sample test case

```
import pymongo
import re
import unittest
import pytest


myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://root:mongodbadmin@18.223.241.113:27017")
mydb = myclient["Ecomm_Product_db"]
mycol = mydb["products"]
cursor = mycol.find({})


class Data_Validation(unittest.TestCase):     

        def test_category_name(self):
                '''Asserts given special characters are not available in the category name'''
                regex = re.compile('[@_!#$/%^*()<>?|}{~:],')
                for name in cursor:
                        assert regex.search(name['category'])==None

        def test_category_type(self):
                '''Asserts category name value type is an string '''
                for name in cursor:
                        assert type(name['category'])==str

        def test_category_minlength(self):
                '''Asserts given min length condition for category name '''
                for name in cursor:
                        assert len(name['category'])>=5

        def test_category_maxlength(self):   
                '''Asserts given max length condition for category name '''
                for name in cursor:
                        assert len(name['category'])<=50
```

Comment: Where does `cursor` come from in these examples?

Comment: cursor is an global variable declared outside the class.and variable returns all the data in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `cursor` is a generator in global scope, the first test to use it will exhaust it, so it'll be empty for all the rest of the test cases. Since the asserts are all in loops, they won't be run. Better to use a [pytest fixture.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html), looking something like:

```py
import pymongo
import re
import unittest
import pytest
from contextlib import closing

@pytest.fixture
def cursor():
    with closing(pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://root:mongodbadmin@18.223.241.113:27017")) as myclient:
        mydb = myclient["Ecomm_Product_db"]
        mycol = mydb["products"]
        yield mycol.find({})

def test_category_name(cursor):
    '''Asserts given special characters are not available in the category name'''
    regex = re.compile('[@_!#$/%^*()<>?|}{~:],')
    for name in cursor:
        assert regex.search(name['category'])==None

def test_category_type(cursor):
    '''Asserts category name value type is an string '''
    for name in cursor:
        assert type(name['category'])==str

def test_category_minlength(cursor):
    '''Asserts given min length condition for category name '''
    for name in cursor:
        assert len(name['category'])>=5

def test_category_maxlength(cursor):   
    '''Asserts given max length condition for category name '''
    for name in cursor:
        assert len(name['category'])<=50
```

You'll get a new cursor each time this way.

Comment: can you please look at the updated code and give me the solution

Comment: code works fine with pylint error(Value 'myclient' is unsubscriptable)

Comment: I'm not a pylint user - but clearly it's mistaken in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55861456/how-to-show-the-break-point-instead-of-assertion-error-while-running-the-test-ca

Comment: can you please look into the link and give me some suggestion