# How to show the break point instead of assertion error while running the test case in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am using pytest to validate db data. I am generating a html report which shows test case result,For failed case it only shows Assertion error, But i need the break point where the test case fails. Can anyone help with this?

Main_methods.py

```
import pymongo
import re
import unittest
import pytest



class Main_methods():     

    def minlength(self,data,category_name,min_length):
       ''' validate the minimum length condition by comparing with db data for a given category

            Parameter: Db data, category name, minium length '''
       for name in data:            
           len(name[category_name])>=min_length
```

test_case.py

```
mport pymongo
import re
import unittest
import pytest
from main_method import Main_methods

class_object=Main_methods()

@pytest.fixture
def data():
    '''Initialise the variable for all the methods using this method and returns the value after the yield keyword.'''
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://root:mongodbadmin@18.223.241.113:27017")
    mydb = myclient["Ecomm_Product_db"]
    mycol = mydb["products"]
    yield mycol.find({})
class Test_Category_Name(): 

    def test_minlength(self,data):
        assert class_object.minlength(data,'category',5)
```

Actual result

```
    def test_minlength(self,data):
>       assert class_object.minlength(data,'category',5)
E       AssertionError: assert None
E        +  where None = <bound method Main_methods.minlength of <main_method.Main_methods object at 0x0326B670>>(<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0346A230>, 'category', 5)
E        +    where <bound method Main_methods.minlength of <main_method.Main_methods object at 0x0326B670>> = <main_method.Main_methods object at 0x0326B670>.minlength

testcase.py:20: AssertionError
```

Result i need(Expected)

```
 def test_category_minlength(data):
            '''Asserts given min length condition for category name '''
            for name in data:
>                   assert len(name['category'])>=5
E                   AssertionError: assert 3 >= 5
E                    +  where 3 = len('SSD')
```

Comment: @brunns please look into it and give some solution

Comment: then where can i assert @brunns

Comment: In the body of your unit tests.

Comment: @brunns, I tried in that way, i updated the latest code above. please look into it

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here, but if you are finding that pytest's asserts aren't enough for you, take a look at https://pyhamcrest.readthedocs.io - you can write pretty sophisticated matchers.

Comment: I exactly need on what value test case gets failing. for example i am giving conditions like len('category_name')>4. testcase 1: pass, testcase 2: fail, 'SSD'(which is less than 4). so i need the failing value. @brunns

Comment: Yup, look at hamcrest for that.

Comment: Also, please stop @ing me. SO is a community, it's not just for me to help you.

Comment: okay @brunns, i will not ping you anymore. Thanks for your guidance

Comment: I don't think there's any way to provide the output you want from the test you've written. Your `minlength` function is guaranteed to return `None`, and I don't think that's what you wanted it to do.

Comment: I can successfully achieve the result pass/fail and also generating html report, but my team wants to know the exact point where the test case fails. Is there anyway to show the result like that ?@ymbirtt

Comment: With your code as written? No. The reason `assert class_object.minlength(...)` is failing is because `minlength` returns `None`. The "exact point where the test case fails" is on your `assert` line, and the precise reason why it fails is that you're asserting a falsey value. I'm almost certain that your `minlength` function is doing the wrong thing, since right now it effectively does nothing.